# Remove all listeners when focus is on contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, contenteditable, dom-events

I have multiple keydown and keyup listeners on my page. I want to disable these events when the focus is on a particular contenteditable div.

How do I do this?

For example, hitting a space pauses my video, but I don't want this from being fired when the contenteditable div is being edited.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the listener, when the event is being fired, check to see if the `event.target` has an ancestor of the contenteditable div, whose events you want to ignore. For example:

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', ({ target }) => {
  if (target.closest('#noevent')) {
    // event was fired on an element which is, or is a descendant 
    // of the noevent element
    // so, stop execution of the listener
    return;
  }
  console.log('listener function continuing...', Date.now());
});
```

```html
<div>normal content</div>
<div contenteditable>editable content</div>
<div contenteditable id="noevent">editable content which will not trigger listener</div>
```

Note that this is not *removing* the listeners - rather, it's programming logic *into* the listeners to ignore certain events, which is probably a lot easier than removing and reattaching the listeners themselves.